# Return rows that do not contain a subset of the same rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table called `activities`that has 2 columns: `nameActivity`and `zipCode`.

How do I write a query that returns all activities *a* for which there are no other activities *b* that:

1. have the same `zipCode`
2. that share the same `nameActivity` as another activity *c*. With other words, for this condition, we need to check that de `nameActivity` of activity *b* is unique.

Example:

```
nameActivity          zipCode
  kayaking              1000
  bouldering            1000
  museum                2000
  paintball             2000
  museum                3000
  karting               4000
```

Following all the conditions above this should result in:

```
nameActivity          zipCode
  paintball             2000
  museum                3000
  karting               4000
```

Comment: (Museum, 3000) has the same name as (Museum, 2000), but you still want it?

Comment: Following the conditions above the (Museum, 3000) should still be in the return values, yes.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the conditions. Why paintball is displayed in output but not bouldering? Can you update the condition that explains the logic very clear?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the condition :

```
SELECT (array_agg(nameActivity))[1]
     , zipCode
  FROM activities
 GROUP BY zipCode
 HAVING count(*) = 1
```

result :

```
array_agg   zipcode
karting     4000
museum      3000
```

(paintball, 2000) is excluded from the result because another nameActivity (museum) exists for the same zipCode.

The second part of the condition is unclear : what means "b share the same nameActivity as another activity c" ???

Answer (score 0):

well, this was a hard one. I think I got it right with some tinkering, hope it helps.

```
with data (nameActivity,          zipCode)as (
Select 'kayaking',              1000 from dual union all
Select  'bouldering',            1000 from dual union all
Select 'museum',               2000 from dual union all
Select 'paintball',             2000 from dual union all
Select 'museum',                3000 from dual union all
Select 'karting',               4000 from dual )
,duplicatesname as(
select nameActivity,zipCode
from(
select d1.nameActivity,max(zipCode) zipCode, count(*) cnt 
from data d1
group by d1.nameActivity)
where cnt >1)
,withoutduplicatename as(
select nameActivity,zipCode
from (
select d1.nameActivity,d1.zipCode,d2.nameActivity na2,d2.zipCode zi2
from data d1
left join duplicatesname d2 on d1.nameActivity = d2.nameActivity
and d1.zipCode != d2.zipCode
) where na2 is null)

,duplicatZipCode as(
select zipCode
from(
select zipCode , count(*) cnt 
from withoutduplicatename d1
group by d1.zipCode)
where cnt >1)

select nameActivity,zipCode
from withoutduplicatename d1
 where d1.zipCode not in (select zipCode from duplicatZipCode)
 order by zipCode
```

Answer (score 0):

I got near.
But kayaking can't be ignored.

> ```
> create table activities (
> nameActivity varchar(30),
> zipCode int
> )
> ```

> ```
> insert into activities 
>    (nameActivity,        zipCode) values
>    ('kayaking',             1000) 
>  , ('bouldering',           1000) 
>  , ('museum',               2000) 
>  , ('paintball',            2000) 
>  , ('museum',               3000) 
>  , ('karting',              4000)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT nameActivity, zipCode
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT nameActivity, zipCode
>     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY zipCode) rn
>     FROM activities a
>     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
>        select 1
>        from activities a2
>        group by a2.zipCode
>        having count(*) = 1
>           and a2.zipCode != a.zipCode
>           and max(a2.nameActivity) = a.nameActivity
>     )
> ) q
> WHERE rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> nameactivity | zipcode
> :----------- | ------:
> kayaking     |    1000
> paintball    |    2000
> museum       |    3000
> karting      |    4000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=721995faf85dc56ccc347a9d0135cb8e)*